# Auto populating a field in access based on the value entered in another field

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2013

I have a database currently containing two tables, the first table being named "tblUser" containing details about individual users, the second table being named "tblTime" containing the actual data that will be inputted by each of those users.

These tables contain a column named "UserLogin" and "Operator", when data is input into tblTime the Operator field will equal a value from the UserLogin field.

I then want the field ContractedHours to be set within tbltime based on the value of the field ContactedHours within tblUser.

tblUser

```
ID    UserLogin   ContractedHours
1     Ollie       8:00
2     Ryan        6:00
```

tblTime

```
ID    Operator   ContactedHours
1     Ollie          x
2     Ryan           y
3     Ollie          x
```

I have shown examples of the tables above. The ID of tblTime will be continuous as this table is ongoing, so i cannot link the two ID's.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this myself over many redesigns of this database, one method is to set a field in the database as:

```
SELECT t.ContractedHours
FROM tblUser AS t
WHERE t.UserLogin = Operator;
```

However by far the most efficient method, was creating a `UserID` field, being an alphanumerical value which would **always** equal a value within the operator field on the other table. I created a relationship between the two fields, and allowed the `ContractedHours` field to autofill.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the data duplicated in two tables. Instead of this method, try mapping the time table to the user table:

tblUser

```
UserID    UserName   
1         Ollie      
2         Ryan
```

tblTime

```
ID  UserID   ContractedHours
1     1          x
2     2          y
3     3          x
```

This method ensures you don't have any duplicated values, and tblTime will use the ID field as it's key, so you can have as many instances of UserID as necessary.

Comment: The Operator field is required in tblTime as that is data that is being input into that table, by logging in to the application that text is used throughout. I need the table to see that the value in the field Operator matches a value in the field UserLogin and then shows the relevant value in ContractedHours within tblTime.

Comment: This method does show the operator value in tblTime, but instead of showing the words it maps to the correct operator in tblUser. You could use a query to see real names instead of number values like so:

`SELECT tblUser.UserName, tblTime.ContractedHours From tblUser INNER JOIN  tblTime ON tblUser.UserID = tblTime.ID;`

Comment: The issue is however that the operator value in tblTime is not shown, it is input from a form, so I am unable to change that to a numerical value. Thanks